# How to break col when text is too large?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with two cols:

a) For the name of the list
b) For an edit button.

col-md-6 works great for when the list's name is short, but when is longer it renders clunky.

**Clunky:**

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="box">Lista: {{ lista.name }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button id="editList" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

It gets worse for mobiles, where the list's name should be on top of the button "Editar".

[image]

Comment: You can use class="col-md-10 col-xs-12" for firstname and class="col-md-2 col-xs-12" for button , xs will be used for smaller screen.

Answer (score 0):

**if you use bootstrap**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
             <h1>welcome to my blog</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6>
             <button class="btn">hello</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**just css**

```
   <div class="contains">
        <div class="text">
             <h1>welcome to my blog</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="button>
             <button class="btn">hello</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
.contains {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.text{
width: 60%;
}
.button{
width: 40%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add (col col-md-6) not (col-md-6)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
        <h1 class="box">Lista: Mi Primary List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
        <button id="editList" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```